# Making a website scale assets and CSS for 3 set resolutions

Tags: css, html, jenkins, image-scaling

I am looking to make a website dynamically scale its assets (png/jpg) and output the appropriate css for three sets of resolutions: 540p, 720p, 1080p

Currently we have assets created for each resolution, so thats 3 sets maintained manually, ideally I want a Jenkins/hudson job to create the assets (by scaling from the highest resolution asset set, maybe use imagemagick commandline) and then generate CSS to make the resolution layout possible.

This is clearly not an old or unique problem, I am wondering what is the best approach to take for this?
The webpage is intended for low computing power embedded devices, which have limited capability, albeit HTML5 supporting. The solution has to be a server side creation of assets and CSS scaling as we cannot rely on the devices to be able to cope with much scaling.

Look forward to your thoughts and replies.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but rather a work-around which is working well and is easier to maintain:

- Replace PNGs with SGVs. Take the highest resolution version and use something like http://vectormagic.com.
- For JPGs take the highest resolution version, but compress it heavily and use something like ImageOptim. This works well for:

  - Browsers are nowadays very good at resizing higher resolution images to smaller ones.
  - Since the pixel density is so high if you are using the full size, the compression (artifacts) will be much less visible. And if your browser is scaling down, artifacts will be less visible because of the smoothing your browser applies.
  - File sizes will be bigger, but not much, since you can use a higher compression and it's getting more efficient with the image's size.

Reference: http://www.fngtps.com/2012/reasonable-ways-to-use-high-resolution-images-on-retina-displays/